# Выборка из БД Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется модель **Purchase**, в которой содержатся покупки, совершённые всеми юзерами и имеющая поля `id, user_id, post_id и timestamp's` Модель выглядит так :

```
class Purchase extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Posts','id');
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User','id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Где, post_id - соответственно id товара, user_id - пользователь купивший.

Так выглядит модель **Posts**

```
class Posts extends Model
{
    public function user(){
       $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
    public function purchases() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Purchase', 'post_id', 'id')->orderBy('id', 'desc')->with("user");
    }
}
```

В методе контроллера :

```
 public function purchases()
    {
        $purchase = Purchase::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

        return view('MyPurchases')->withPurchase($purchase);
    }
```

Я должен сделать выборку покупок, которые принадлежат к залогиненому юзеру, во-вторых сосчитать кол-во покупок от каждого товара, отсортировать покупки по дате и оставить только по одной последней покупке на каждый товар. Для этой покупки необходимо вывести данные о товаре и о продавце. Не могу придумать в каком направлении копать. Думал как-нибудь через `distinct()`, но не вышло.

Есть мысль все покупки одного человека, которые относятся к одному посту просто заносить в 1 строку в БД, обновляя после каждой покупки и каждый раз увеличивая число покупок на 1 и обновляя timestamp. Как это лучше сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На счет обновления строки после каждой покупки "ну такое", точно не смею сказать, как лучше б было, если сильно нагруженным проект станет, точно придется менять логику, по твоему коду:

Создай отдельный метод для повторного кода, реализацию смотри как тебе лучше, к примеру вот так:

```
private function updatePurchaseAndPost($purchase Purchase, $post Posts, $isNew = false) {
  if ($post->amount >= 1) {
      $purchase->amount = $purchase->amount + 1;
      $post->amount = $post->amount - 1;
      $post->sold_amount = $post->sold_amount + 1;
  } 

  if($isNew) {
    $purchase->post_id = $post->id;
    $purchase->user_id = Auth::user()->id;  
  }

  $purchase->save();
  $post->save();
}
```

А твой код станет таким:

```
public function purchase($id){
    $post = Posts::find($id);
    $purchase = Purchase::where([
        ['post_id', '=', $post->id],
        ['user_id','=', Auth::user()->id]
    ])->first();

    if($purchase){
        $this->updatePurchaseAndPost($purchase, $post);
    }
    else {
        $purchase = new Purchase();
        $this->updatePurchaseAndPost($purchase, $post, true);
    }

    return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
}
```

немного поясню: передаешь объект `Purchase` и `Posts`, и параметр, `$isNew` - новый элемент или просто идет обновление.

p.s. если есть ошибки по синтаксису, ссори, не очень привык править код на `sublime`.

Comment: да и, в первом условии `Purchase::where([
            ['post_id', '=', $post->id],
            ['user_id','=', Auth::user()->id]
        ])->first()`, когда целый вызов в условии, так лучше не делай, точнее не делай так, тем более, дальше у тебя идет такой же код, получается ты два раза делаешь запрос к БД, сперва проверяешь, а потом чтобы изменить опять это делаешь, поэтому вынес в отдельную переменную `$purchase` и работаешь с ним

Comment: Окей, спасибо. Ну по поводу реализации - просто ничего другого в голову не пришло. Думаю, конечно, можно было как-то отсортировать данные. Но маловато опыта в этих вопросах.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему вторым способом - обновляя одну строку после каждой покупки. Получился такой код, не самый красивый, правда. Как лучше разобраться с двумя идентичными кусками?

```
 public function purchase($id){

        $post = Posts::find($id);
        if(Purchase::where([
            ['post_id', '=', $post->id],
            ['user_id','=', Auth::user()->id]
        ])->first()){
            $purchase=Purchase::where([
                ['post_id', '=', $post->id],
                ['user_id','=', Auth::user()->id]
            ])->first();
            if ($post->amount >= 1) {
                $purchase->amount = $purchase->amount + 1;
                $post->amount = $post->amount - 1;
                $post->sold_amount = $post->sold_amount + 1;
            }
            $purchase->save();
        }
        else {
            $purchase = new Purchase();
            if ($post->amount >= 1) {
                $purchase->amount = $purchase->amount + 1;
                $post->amount = $post->amount - 1;
                $post->sold_amount = $post->sold_amount + 1;
            }

            $purchase->post_id = $post->id;
            $purchase->user_id = Auth::user()->id;


            $purchase->save();
        }
        $post->save();

        return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
    }
```